# Using tesseract OCR in android

Tags: android-ndk

Can anyone please provide a clear instruction on using tessaract ocr as a library in android development. I'm currently developing an application to perform text extraction. I'm using cygwin to clone tesseract from github but i'm facing problem on "ndk-build" step. How to set my application project path in cygwin in order to make the ndk-build successful? `NDK_PROJECT_PATH := $(strip $(NDK_PROJECT_PATH))` from build-local.mk in android ndk folder. PLEASE HELP ME

Answer (score -1):

You may use [Tesseract](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&ved=0CEQQFjAC&url=http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/&ei=7h2CUa7BHcftrAfH0IH4Aw&usg=AFQjCNHJqIxrcpf5ItbWx8JTRFJOvQIXVA&sig2=Rz6h8_nIkQNOwbWOlBRfJQ&bvm=bv.45960087,d.bmk). It's powerful library and it has java wrapper [Tess4j](http://tess4j.sourceforge.net) too.